# Different behavior with the same logic applied in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, comparison

I need to filter a column of strings types to only return values ​​that are equal to 'NORMAL'. Applying the following codes returned different dataframes:

1 - `df = df[(df['column_name'] == 'NORMAL')]`

2 - `df = df.drop(df[(df['column_name'] != 'NORMAL'].index)`

3 - `df = df.drop(df[(~df['column_name'].str.contains('NORMAL'))].index)`

The resulting dataframe at 2 and 3 are equal but different from 1. The expected dataframe is made by example 1.

Am I missing something or is there a logical difference between the codes ?

Comment: Do you have duplicated indices? Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Hi @mozway, the duplicated indeces were exactly the problem. I reset the index before applying the code and the behavior was the same for the 3 examples. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @mozway, the difference in the return between the 3 example codes was in the index, when resetting the index the problem was solved.